# Finding point coordinates using their point data in kilometers

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, arcgis, qgis

I have some point data that has kilometers from the specific point of the road. I want to extract the lat and long. How could it be done?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. If you have a point GIS layer, it's very easy to get the long/lat of the points. (Nothing to do with the kilometers along the road). Also please specify which software you are using, QGIS or Arc?

Comment: Also, you might move this question over to [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have accident data that I take them from the police station, unfortunately, they save accident point as a kilometer from that police station instead of lat/long. also, I am working with QGIS, now I can not change them to lat/long because as far as I know the software and webs provide euclidean distance and roads as you know is not a direct path

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get a precise set of Lat/Long, unless there is more detail in the data recorded at the police station.

One solution might be to buffer the police station to 1 km then select all the road sections within the 1 km buffer.  If the police data holds the road name or ID you could then link your accident to the road section identified in the buffer.  Theoretically you could then take the center point along the road, however this would be misleading as if you create a map of this it will create a false impression of where accidents occur.

Comment: Even though you did not mention GRASS GIS in your tags, there is a GRASS module `v.net.iso` that splits a road network into "iso-distances" from some center point. This might be of help. More details [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.iso)

Comment: Not spent much time in GRASS, so didn't know.  Fundamentally I also assumed an even distribution of police stations!  If a road is 50 km long with only one police station then the accidents would always be within 1 km of that Police station.

Comment: Why is that? Do drivers get nervous as they approach the police station, then have an accident?  ;-)